# What does editElementQuery do?

Tags: aem, richtext

I've came across some examples of a richtext field that has a property called editElementQuery but nobody says what it does. I couldn't find any documentation on it either.
One of the examples is in the stackoverflow question bellow:
[AEM/CQ5 html5smartimage filename lost on image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801859/aem-cq5-html5smartimage-filename-lost-on-image-upload)

Does anybody know what this is suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this field is here for storing the selector of the element that should be opened / edited in case of inline edition of that property.
If not fed, the first block element will be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation what does editElementQuery do:
https://medium.com/@koen_/boost-your-aem-authors-experience-85b2aef04422

Here is a small piece of _cq_editConfig.xml file where I have used this field:

```
<cq:inplaceEditing
        jcr:primaryType="cq:InplaceEditingConfig"
        active="{Boolean}true"
        editorType="text">
    <config jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            editElementQuery="div.rich-text-component__text">
        <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            ...
        </rtePlugins>
    </config>
</cq:inplaceEditing>
```

I share this config here because I had difficulties in finding where to put this editElementQuery property.